# Fix div position when zoom out

Tags: html, css

I used div as an alternative to table because of some requirements but I cannot make its position fixed when zommed in/out. I only did some inline css to have it aligned as shown but not working when zoomed. I'll only be using this for browsers and not for mobile. It's my first time to use divs and Im still in the process of learning. Please help

```css
#form {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}

label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
}

input {
 display: table-cell; 
}

#destination {
 width: 185px;
}

#MODEL {
 width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id= "form">
<form action= "" method= "POST"> 
  <div class= "form-group">
   <label for= "model"><b>MODEL: </b></label>
     <select ID= "MODEL"  name= "MODEL" size= "1" onClick= "getDestination()" style= "margin-left: -160px; margin-top: 5px;  width: 138px">
      <option value = "" selected= "selected">Select Model</option>
      <option value = "A"> A </option>
      <option value = "B"> B </option>
      <option value = "C"> C </option>
     </select>
  </div>

  <div class= "form-group">
   <label for= "requestor"><b> REQUESTOR: </b></label>
    <input size= "50" type= "text" name= "REQUESTOR" id= "REQUESTOR" style= "margin-left:50px; margin-top: 5px"/>
  </div>
   

  <div class= "form-group">
   <label for= "status"><b> STATUS: </b></label>
    <select id= "STATUS" name= "STATUS" size= "1" style= "margin-left: -238px; margin-top: 5px"/>
     <option value= "Open" selected= "selected"> Open </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class= "form-group">
   <label for= "request_date"><b> REQUEST_DATE: </b></label>
    <input type= "date" style= "margin-left: -205px; margin-top: 5px" name="REQUEST_DATE">
  </div>
  
  
  <div class= "form-group">
   <label for= "destination"><b>DESTINATION: </b></label>
     <select id= "destination" name= "destination[]" style= "margin-left: -35px; margin-top: 5px"/>
      <option value= "" selected="selected">Select Destination</option>
      <option value = "A"> A </option>
      <option value = "B"> B </option>
      <option value = "C"> C </option>
     </select>
      <input type= "button" id= "add" value= "Add Destination">
  </div>
  
<br> 
<input type= "submit" name= "submit" id= "submit_form" value= "Submit"> &nbsp <input type= "reset" value= "Reset" id= "reset"><br /><br />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but it really should be spelled "requester", without the "o".

Comment: Important: I neglected to mention in my answer that I switched from using `px` to using `vw/vh` (viewport units) to ensure the result scales nicely. Viewport units will retain their size/shape when the browser is zoomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just a little more div structure around your form elements.

For example, each row (of label/input pairs) should be wrapped in a div. You already have that, called "form-group".

Then, each left-side item should be wrapped in a div, and each right-side item wrapped in a div. Yes, it adds to the HTML structure - but look how nicely we can style it. *(View and Run the code snippet to see...)*

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-left col-inline">
            <label for="REQUESTOR"><b> REQUESTOR: </b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right col-inline">
            <input type="text" name="REQUESTOR" id="REQUESTOR"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Also note that capitalization matters. If you use all-caps for the ID, then you must use all-caps for the `for=` on the associated label tag.*

```css
#form{width:80vw;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;text-align:left;}
#destination{width:25vw;}
#MODEL{}
#REQUESTOR{width:30vw;}
#STATUS{}
#REQUEST_DATE{}
#destination{}

.row {margin-top:2vh;}
.col-inline{display:inline-block;XXXborder:1px solid green;}
.col-left {width:30vw;text-align:right;}
.col-right{width:40vw;text-align: left;}
```

```html
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="POST"> 
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
   <label for="MODEL"><b>MODEL: </b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
   <select ID="MODEL" name="MODEL" onClick= "getDestination()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Model</option>
    <option value="A"> A </option>
    <option value="B"> B </option>
    <option value="C"> C </option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
   <label for="REQUESTOR"><b> REQUESTOR: </b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
     <input type="text" name="REQUESTOR" id="REQUESTOR"/>
  </div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
   <label for="STATUS"><b> STATUS: </b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
   <select id="STATUS" name="STATUS">
    <option value="Open" selected="selected"> Open </option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
   <label for="REQUEST_DATE"><b> REQUEST_DATE: </b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
   <input type="date" id="REQUEST_DATE" name="REQUEST_DATE">
  </div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
     <label for= "destination"><b>DESTINATION: </b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
   <select id="destination" name="destination[]">
    <option value="">Select Destination</option>
    <option value="A"> A </option>
    <option value="B"> B </option>
    <option value="C"> C </option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" id="add" value="Add"/>
  </div>
 </div>

<br>
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-left col-inline">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_form" value= "Submit">
  </div>
  <div class="col-right col-inline">
   <input type= "reset" value= "Reset" id= "reset">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
```